# Javascript onunload occurs after new page is loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, onunload

In my website I try to limit a certain page to one session per user only, to do so I used cookies (can't use Session variable) and the `onunload"` event of the body element in the masterpage- there I delete the cookie and in `CreateChildControl` of the specific webpart I check for the cookie/create it if it doesn't exist.

The problem is that when I move from one page to another- the `createchildcontrols` occurs before the `onunload` event of the previous page which is weird- what happens is that the cookie still exists because it hasn't been deleted by the previous page yet.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Onunload is not reliable **and should not be used for any important purposes**. What if the browser crashes etc.?

If you want to limit to one session per user simply delete/invalidate the old session if a new one is created for some reason.

Comment: I can't use Session variable- I'm developing the site over sharepoint and "enablesessionstate" is not active in the farm(and it's not up to me to decide weather to activate it or not)

Comment: Furthermore- I've put expiration on the cookies of 1 hour in case the browser/the computer crash

Comment: I agree and that's one of the reasons I'm looking for different solution :)-
Any suggested solution without Session variable ?

Comment: Hi, any other solutions ? 
If I do use session, do I need to change the global.asax file ? because again - we're developing over sharepoint and it would be kind of a problem to change it..